Cannot Open PluginRegistration
When I use Net Framework， After downloading PluginRegistration (version: 9.1.0.187) through NuGet, the program did not respond when opening PluginRegistration.exe. By checking the system logs, the following errors were found. How should I do it?
system log:
System. InvalidOperationException in Microsoft. PowerPlatform. Tooling. BatchedTelemetry. TelemetryChannel. BatchedTelemetryChannel. StartUploadProcess() PowerPlatform. Tooling. BatchedTelemetry. Telemetry Channel. BatchedTelemetry Channel. Flush() is available in Microsoft Application Insights. TelemetryClient. Flush() is available in Microsoft Crm. Tools. PluginRegistration. App. DisposeApp() is located in System Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchException(System. Exception in System Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System. Object, System. Delegate, System. Object, Int32, System. Delegate) in System Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System. Windows. Threading. DispatcherPriority, System. TimeSpan, System. Delegate, System. Object, Int32) in MS.Win32. HwndSubclass Subclass WndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) in MS.Win32. UnsafeNativeMethods DispatchMessage(System. Windows. Interop. MSG ByRef) in System Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System. Windows. Threading. DispatcherFrame) in System Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System. Object in System Windows.Application.RunInternal(System. Windows in Microsoft Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.App.Main()
I hope to open the application successfully.

Have you tried using XrmToolBox? I believe it will work. Please give it a try and let me know if the issue persists.


thanks. It works successfully using XrmToolBox.

Happy to help buddy !
